# Display value from array in html without commas , using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array containing user inputs and I want to display the last five inputs from the array in HTML:

```
function display_last_five()
 {
   var e = "<hr/>";   
     e += array.slice(Math.max(array.length - 5, 0)) + " ";
   document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML = e;
}
```

What I get:

```
Input1,Input2,Input3
```

What I want:

```
Input1 Input2 Input3
```

In there a way to manipulate the output or is the input stored incorrect?

Comment: You're using the default `toString` implementation of an array; use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) instead.

Comment: BTW, your title is a little odd considering the content of the question; you may want to [edit] it to talk about commas rather than quotation marks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woul try using [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) instead of string concatenation.

```
function display_last_five()
 {
   var e = "<hr/>";   
     e += array.slice(Math.max(array.length - 5, 0)).join(" ");
     document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML = e;
}
```

Comment: will try this now. looks much cleaner thank you

Answer (score 2):

```js
var array = ["input1","input2","input3","input4","input4","input5","input6","input7"];
var newHTML = [];
var count=0;
for (var i =array.length; i != 0; i--) {
  if(count==6) break
    newHTML.push(array[i]);
    count++
}
$(".element").html(newHTML.join(" "));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using vanilla JavaScript :

```js
function displayLastFive ( array )
{ 
  // Get the output element
  let result = document.getElementById( 'result' );
  
  // Show the last elements of the array, to a maximum of 5 elements
  result.innerHTML = `<hr/>${ array.slice( -5 ).join( ' ' ) }`;
}

displayLastFive( [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] );
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function display_last_five()
  {
    var e = "<hr/>";   
      e += array.slice(Math.max(array.length - 5, 0)) + " ";
    document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML = e.replace(/,/g, ' '))
 }
```

Use .replace() to remove all ',' and replace with a space

Comment: this works, thank you